# How to get on keyPressed in a JPanel CTRL+m?

Tags: swing, jpanel, onkeypress

I'm trying to implement a JPopupMenu over a text editor component. It should be activated on CTRL+m. Can I do that inside

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

}
```

and if yes, how? Because if I try

```
if(arg0.isControlDown()&&arg0.getKeyChar()=='m')
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: which of the 2 condition (ctrlDown or KeyChar) is false? in addition are you sure that keyPressed method is called?does the text editor component has the keyboard focus?

Comment: both condition must be true. I need CTRL+M pressed. Yes it's called. If I try to press CTRL alone it works.

Comment: how can it work only with ctrl pressed? there is an && in your condition, both values must be true.

Comment: that was the answer to your question: "are you sure that keyPressed method is called?" Yes, If I use only ctrl just to test it, it works. The problem is that when ctrl is pressed, arg0.getKeyChar() is just empty even with m pressed.

Comment: according to the Java API (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29) could be a case problem (try 'M' instead of 'm'), but if getKeyChar return an empty value a really have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought it was something to do with CTRL+M being the same thing as a carriage-return/line feed, but that wasn't true.  Try:

```
if(e.isControlDown() && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M) {
    System.out.println("pressed");
    menu.setVisible(true);
}
```

I couldn't get it to work using chars with e.getKeyChar() either, but the getKeyCode() works for me.  Great, it works.  But I'm the type that has to know why.  So I found [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29):

> KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events
>   are not intended for reporting of
>   character input. Therefore, the values
>   returned by this method are guaranteed
>   to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED
>   events